# Server and client have same host (localhost), but different ports (8080, 3000). Can I use Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, graphql

My server runs on localhost:8080.
My client runs on localhost:3030.
I want to use httponly cookie to set a refresh token to manage JWT access token refreshing and expiry.

My server code looks like this

```js
app.use(
  cors({
    origin:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
        ? "abc.com"
        : "localhost:3000",
    credentials: true
  })
);
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, path: "/graphql" });
```

On the client, I have

```js
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: `localhost:8080/graphql`,
  credentials: "include"
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link
});
```

As expected I get this error:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/graphql. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

I expect this because I am making the request from localhost:3000 that goes to localhost:8080.

Now if I change to allow any origin using `*`,

```js
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "abc.com" : "*",
    credentials: true
  })
);
```

I get `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://localhost:8080/graphql’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).`

So what option do I have? Is there no way to make  credentialed request with a httponly cookie when I have server and client running on different ports?

Comment: As far as I can see, your existing server code should work as expected  if you use `process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
        ? "https://abc​.com"
        : "http://localhost:3000"` — that is, include the protocol part in the origin value. `localhost:3000`, without the protocol part, isn’t a valid origin — it’ll never match anything. It’s not clear why you say, *“I expect this because I am making the request from localhost:3000 that goes to localhost:8080”*. Why do you expect that? You should instead expect it to work — that’s the whole point of CORS-enabling the localhost:8080 server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the actual Origin (`http://localhost:3000`) in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

The error message is just telling you that the wildcard (`*`) is not supported.

Comment: If you see my server code, I actually have tried this `origin: localhost:3000`. And I got this error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/graphql. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use nginx running inside a docker container as a proxy. And this nginx proxies both server and client with a same port number. This way the server and the client looks like they are both running on the same port and we don't have the CORS problem.

I am using Ubuntu, so `host.docker.internal` is not available yet. Please see https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264.

My docker compose looks like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: local-nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/local:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    command: [nginx-debug, "-g", "daemon off;"]
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:172.17.0.1"
```

The docker instance sees 172.17.0.1 as the host IP address

My nginx config looks like

```
server 
{
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000/;
    }    

    location /graphql
    {
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:8080/graphql;
    }

    location /health
    {
        return 200 '{"message": "healthy"}';
        add_header Content-Type application/json;
    }
}
```

My Client runs on 3000 and server runs on 8080. But both are now proxied through 8000.